# Draw outline around arbitrary html range

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to draw an `outline` around an arbitrary range in an HTML document.
i.e. I would like to do something like:

```
var start=document.getElementById('foo');
var end=document.getElementById('bar');
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(start, 0);
range.setEnd(end, 0);
```

and then have an `outline` appear arround `range`.

I have so far looked at the following approaches:
1) `document.execCommand` but sadly it only seems possible to apply a background or foreground colour via this method and not a border or outline of any kind.
2) Setting `range` as the document `selection`, however seemingly css does not allow a border or outline on the `::selection` selector.

Does anyone know of a way that this might be possible, either via the above or some other method(s)? Perhaps it is possible to compute the text area somehow and then draw it with a canvas or one or more absolute positioned divs?

Assumptions:

Note: I only need this to happen temporarily while a menu pops up from the host program, after which it should dissapear again, so it is safe to ignore things like the window scrolling after drawing the rectangle or more content added to document etc.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the beginnings of a solution using jQuery to get the elements of interest.

The sample code:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>This is some text...</p>
    <p class="foo">This is some text...</p>
    <p>This is some text...</p>
    <p>This is some text...<b>with bold</b></p>
    <p class="bar">This is some text...</p>
    <p>This is some text...</p>
    <p>This is some text...</p>    
</div>
```

and some CSS:

```
.outline {
    outline: 1px solid blue; 
}
```

The jQuery looks like:

```
var lastElm = $(".bar");
$(".foo").nextUntil(lastElm).add(lastElm).wrapAll('<div class="outline" />');
```

I set up a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cf9V8/

One solution is to wrap the elements of interest in a `<div>` and apply a style to show the outline.

However, you need to think about the case when your start/end elements are within separate blocks.  In this case, a wrapper could break the layout.

I can tweak this with some feedback.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect this is going to run into some issues with more complex edge cases that involve blocks etc. as you say, however I will try it out inside the app and see how problematic it really is... Just have to convert it to regular JS on this side quickly first as sadly the app does not seem to work with jquery.

Comment: @MalcolmMacLeod I am not sure what app you are referring to so I can't offer any advice without more details.  However, if you get a prototype working in jQuery, a JavaScript programmer can code up something with the same functionality.  If you had some sample HTML that you might encounter in the real world, that would help to test out the jQuery prototype.  Please keep us posted. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/AmQbx/

A simple way (not cleanest) of doing this is:

Get the position of the first element and the last element:

```
var startElem = $('#foo'), 
    startPos = startElem.position(), 
    endElem = $('#bar').position(), 
    endPos = endElem.position();
```

Make a new div that streches from beginning till end like so:

```
var selection = $('<div/>').css({
    'z-index': 1000;
    position: absolute,
    background: none,
    border: '1px solid #F00',
    top: startPos.top,
    left: startPos.left,
    width: startElem.css('width').replace('px',''),
    height: ( endPos.top + parseFloat(endElem.css('height').replace('px','') ) ) - startPos.top
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: In this approach, the outlined elements are taken out of the flow of the document, which I find useful and interesting.

Comment: Hrm, three mistakes I think. 1) Extra .position() for endElem variable 2) `z-index` needs to be escaped because of the dash 3) Missing closing brace on the height line.  - Even with those corrections though I can't seem to get it to do anything insdie jsfiddle, I'm not overly familiar with jQuery so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.